# Spring @Value with arraylist split and default empty list

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am struggling in obtaining both of the behaviors requested in the title.
1) I have a property file like this:

```
my.list=a,b,c
```

2) If that property is not present I want an empty list

Why the following is throwing me syntax error?

```
@Value("#{'${my.list}'.split(',') : T(java.util.Collections).emptyList()}")
```

Comment: I am not sure, if you can do a nested SPEL

Comment: Confirmed: I get the "," inside of the first array element :(

Comment: try this: `@Value("#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList('${my.list:}')}")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use nested SPEL. one way to achieve this is

```
@Value("${server.name:#{null}}")
private String someString;

private List<String> someList;

@PostConstruct
public void setList() {
  someList = someString == null ? Collections.emptyList() : Arrays.asList(someString.split(","));
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There is a way to get it working:

```
@Value("#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList('${my.list:}')}") 
private List<String> list;
```

After the colon at `my.list:` you can set the default value. For now its emtpy.

Comment: will it split also ?

Comment: yes it will split

Comment: yes it split, but where is the .split command in case I don't want ',' char

Answer (score 3):

Did came across similar requirement. Below is one of the possible way of doing this :

```
@Value("#{'${some.key:}'.split(',')}")
Set<String> someKeySet;
```

I think similar should apply for List as well.
Pay attention to ":" after property name. It defaults to blank string which in turn would give empty list or set.

Comment: It does not create an empty Set, it creates a Set with one empty string element [""].

Answer (score -2):

The best way to achieve this will be

```
@Value("#{'${my.list:}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> myList;
```

If key is not present in application.properties, we are initialising with a empty list.

Comment: No, this creates a list with one empty string in it.