# Spring, inject list value with SPEL using split and default empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want this property mapped on application.properties

```
my.list=a;b;c
```

converted to a List (or eventually a String[]); there are 2 requirements;

1. my.list is separated by ; char
2. my.list could be empty

I tried with:

```
@Value("#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList('${my.list:}'.split(';'))}")
```

but it doesn't work as expected, as passing multiple values convert the list with a single element "a,b,c".

PS
I already know there is a very similare [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367006/spring-value-with-arraylist-split-and-default-empty-list), however the solution was not tested with separator different from ','.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```java
@Value("#{'${my.list:}'.split(';')}#{T(java.util.Collections).emptyList()}")
List<String> listValue;
```

Comment: no, it will fill the list with one empty item

Comment: Updated - an empty `my.list` will produce a zero size list